# Backtracking using right hand rule in a maze

Tags: c#, maze

I'm trying to solve the maze by using the right hand rule, but my backtracking is not working correctly. Whenever it hits a dead end, it just stops traversing. It could be something wrong with my if else statement. However, it's hard to debug in windows form, and I can't even figure out what I did wrong. Would anyone tell me what is wrong with my function ? Thank you.
This is what I have for my maze:

```
          public char[,] navigateMouse()
          {
               // check south
               if (mouseMaze[yPos + 1, xPos] == ' ')
               {
                    //mark the trail with '.'
                    mouseMaze[yPos, xPos] = '.';
                    mouseMaze[yPos + 1, xPos] = 'M';
                    yPos++;
               }
               // check east
               else if (mouseMaze[yPos + 1, xPos] == 'X' && mouseMaze[yPos, xPos + 1] == ' ')
               {
                    mouseMaze[yPos, xPos] = '.';
                    mouseMaze[yPos, xPos + 1] = 'M';
                    xPos++;
               }
               // check north
               else if (mouseMaze[yPos + 1, xPos] == 'X' && mouseMaze[yPos, xPos + 1] == 'X' && 
                    mouseMaze[yPos - 1, xPos] == '.')
               {
                    mouseMaze[yPos, xPos] = '.';
                    mouseMaze[yPos - 1, xPos] = 'M';
                    yPos--;
               }
               // check west
               else if (mouseMaze[yPos + 1, xPos] == 'X' && mouseMaze[yPos, xPos + 1] == 'X' && 
                    mouseMaze[yPos - 1, xPos] == 'X' && mouseMaze[yPos - 1, xPos] == '.')
               {
                    mouseMaze[yPos, xPos] = '.';
                    mouseMaze[yPos, xPos - 1] = 'M';
                    xPos--;
               }
               return mouseMaze;
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

You bug is a logical bug.  Think about how you are designing it.

The mouse will travel to a square, then check all of the sides.  If the mouse is at a dead end, then all of the sides will be closed, except one, but that one side will be visited.

Thus, if you end up with the mouse not moving, you need to backtrack.  Follow the path you have made until the right-hand-rule gives you a space you haven't visited yet.

Comment: so it means that I have to check for every directions whenever I get to a square, if 4 sides happens to be closed, then I have to backtrack and follow the trail that I have been marked. Is that what you mean ?